# Debugging Javascript using IE Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging

I've been using the above tool for some time now but recently I've had an issue when trying to debug javascript. I get the following message:

Unable to attach to process. Another debugger might be attached to the process

Visual studio seems to be debugging the javascript for me, which I don't want it to do. Any idea how I stop this?

Comment: You could kill the Visual Studio related threads in the Task Manager... maybe that would help

Answer (score 4):

Go to Tools->Options, then expand "Debugging", click on "Just-In-Time" and uncheck "Script". That should do the trick.

Comment: This didn't work. I tried restarting VS after changing the settings as well but I still get the same error message. Odd as that seems to be exactly the setting I would expect to change